# Store in a map a key with multiple values

Tags: java, collections

I want to store in a map keys with multiple values.
For example : i am reading from an ArrayList the keys which are Strings and from another ArrayList the values which are integers:

```
Keys                     Values
humans                   50
elfs                     20
dwarfs                   30
humans                   40
elfs                     10
```

and i want to store these informations like this: Map < String, ArrayList < Integer>>

```
[humans = {50,40}]
[elfs = {20,10}]
[dwarfs = {30}]
```

It is there possible to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `Map < String, ArrayList < Integer>>`?

Comment: I'd say 'Array' is unneeded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this:

```
public class StringToListInt {
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> stringToListInt;

    public StringToListInt() {
        stringToListInt = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    }

    public void addInt( String string, Integer someValue ) {
        List<Integer> listInt = stringToListInt.get( string );
        if ( listInt == null ) {
            listInt = new ArrayList<String>();
            stringToListInt.put( string, listInt );
        }
        listInt.add( someValue );
    }

    public List<Integer> getInts( String string ) {
        return stringToListInt.get( string );
    }
}
```

If you add in some Generics, I imagine you would end up with something very similar to Guava's MultiMap without the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the [Guava MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).  Alternatively, your

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

will also accomplish this.  When doing a `put`, determine if there is already a list associated with the key; if there is then your `put` will be a `get(key).add(value)`, otherwise it will be a `put(new List(value))`.  Likewise a `remove` will remove a value from the associated list, or else will completely remove the list if this will result in an empty list.

Also, a `Map<String, HashSet<Integer>>` will probably result in better performance than a map of lists; obviously don't do this if you want to associate duplicate values with a key.

Comment: Can you explain in what way the Guava Multimap is better than the other?

Comment: It's already been implemented and tested, so it will save time in the long run.

Comment: I use the map of `List` strategy all the time.  It is sometimes more confusing, but on the plus side it is one less classpath dependency to worry about.

Comment: That should be a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, not ArrayList.